# Flutter Sparkline Chart double X and Y Axis Bug

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, fl-chart

im quite new to flutter and having some problems, i could not find in the fl chart documentation

anyone know why my Line Chart shows double X and Y Axis? And how to remove the double axes?
Also the X and Y Axis Values are chaing dynamicly, how can i give them a defined value like 1-1000 and display every 50-Step? so 0,50,100,150 etc ...

Im using FL Chart Library.
[image]

```
    Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: LineChart(
                                LineChartData(
                                    borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),


                                    lineBarsData: [
                                      LineChartBarData(
                                        spots: generateUserLoginData(dashIntranet),
                                        isCurved: false,
                                        barWidth: 2,

                                        colors: [
                                          MD_Blue
                                        ]

                                    )
                                  ]

                                )


                              )


                            )


                        )
```

Sorry for my English, thanks in advance!